# App Engine deploy to somewhere that is not project_id.appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Exactly as title says, am trying to deploy project to App Engine but whenever try always says deploying to project_id.appspot.com

I have domain recently transferred from original registrar to Google Domains, how deploy to my domain instead of project_id.appspot.com because nobody will go there? I have been working for months on project and need to get online within next couple of weeks before end of month

Comment: Just a note, when you do get it set up correctly, it is still accessible at the default URL. This can be useful if you happen to be deploying different modules and/or versions at the same time. You are able to access them specifically by URL. My app rollout phase doesn't hit users all at once, so I can have the new version and old serving until everyone has migrated over. See here for how the URLs are set up https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-routed

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your domain to direct traffic to the appspot location, rather than deploy the code "to" your domain.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application

Comment: I'm not using python

Comment: @CRCX001 : just replace "python" with "go" in that url. Instructions are pretty much the same regardless of the language.

Comment: and this will send to my domain, yes?

Comment: Yes, but you have the logic reversed, it will send traffic to your domain to the App Engine application, so you still deploy to your APPID.appspot.com location and you can always access your application on the appspot domain.